# jQuery form zip code to state function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, syntax

I'm trying to convert a preexisting javascript function into a jQuery function.
The function comes from http://javascript.internet.com/forms/zip-to-state.html
and aims to convert a user-entered zip code into a state. I'm using jQuery 1.3.2, with all the necessary plugins, but I'm not very familiar with jQuery syntax and how to convert this from plain ol' Javascript syntax.

The setState function takes two parameters, the zip code element and the state element, so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$('$zip_code').change( function () { setState($(this), $('#state')); });
```

Any thoughts on this syntax? Thanks, Dakota

```
function getState(zip) {
    if ((parseInt(zipString.substr(zip / 4, 1), 16) & Math.pow(2, zip % 4)) && (zip.length == 5))
        for (var i = 0; i < stateRange.length; i += 7)
            if (zip <= 1 * stateRange.substr(i, 5))
                return stateRange.substr(i + 5, 2);
    return null;
}

function setState(txtZip, optionBox) {
    if (txtZip.value.length != 5 || isNaN(txtZip.value / 4)) {
        optionBox.options[0].selected = true;
        alert("Please enter a 5 digit, numeric zip code.");
        return;
    }

    var state = getState(txtZip.value);

    for (var i = 0; i < optionBox.options.length; i++)
        if (optionBox.options[i].value == state)
            return optionBox.options[i].selected = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < optionBox.options.length; i++)
        if (optionBox.options[i].value == "XX")
            return optionBox.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave the getState and setState functions just as they are, but you should really read up on jQuery before you go asking questions on how to use it. If you don't even know the syntax, you might want to read up on how to use it.

Like Aberon said, use blur in this situation and change '$zip_code' to '#zip_code', where 'zip_code' corresponds to:

```
<input type="text" id="zip_code" name="whatever_you_want" />
```

You also want a select box with an id of 'state':

```
<select id="state">
   ... options ...
</select>
```

Aberon's solution still wont work, however, because it is incomplete...

```
$('#zip_code').blur( function () { setState($(this)[0], $('#state')[0]); });
```

You want to get the value from the zip_code input element, thus the val() call. You also want the DOM element for the select box with id == 'state', so instead of using the array returned by $('#state'), you want the first element.

Try it out, I hope this helped.

-Stephen

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. My background is in PHP, but obviously the $ should have been a #. Also, thanks for pointing me in the right direction with calling the first element of the DOM array for the #state element. After playing around, I found that the original function did not require the #zip_code value as a parameter, but rather the whole element. The appropriate function call turned out to be: 

$('#zip_code').blur( function () { setState($(this)[0], $('#state')[0]); }); 

Many thanks for your thorough answer. Best, Dakota.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. I updated my post to make the changes you mentioned. It sure would have been helpful if whoever wrote those zip and state functions added some comments regarding how to use them. I just glanced at it quickly, assuming that it took a string as a parameter and not a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your `zip` field is a drop down you would probably be better off using either [`blur`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur) or [`keyup`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keyup) in your function.

```
$('#zip_code').blur( function () { setState($(this), $('#state')); });
```

I also changed `$zip_code` to `#zip_code`.